# Vista Reverts My Code On Me

Tags: file, version, type-conversion

For some strange reason, when I move a PHP file from one folder to another, Vista copies an old version of the file instead of the current version. This really screws up the web application I'm working on and causes me to waste time in figuring out the problem.

What the hell is going on here and how do I prevent Vista from copying or moving previous versions of a file?

To explain a little further, when I open my PHP file in its current location I see the current version of my code. When I copy the file to the new location and open the file I see an old version of the code.

Comment: I've no idea, but don't copy code around, use source control.

Comment: If they are simply files on a harddrive, this is impossible. If they are integrated into some sort of source-control, what source control provider is it?

Comment: @devinb: Nothing is impossible.

Comment: @Spencer. The behaviour described IS impossible. If I take a txt file reading "Hello world" then I save it, then I open it, change the value to "Goodbye world" then save it again. At that point, the "Hello" *does not exist* anymore. That is, assuming I actually saved it. If I copy the file somewhere else, and it shows "Hello world" that means that I never actually saved it.

Comment: The only way for a file to actually have versions is if the file *internally* holds revision information (as some word documents do), which the Vista 'copy' function would not have the ability to mess with (all it is doing is creating another copy of the bits involved) or if there is an external versioning system involved. In which case, we would need to know what that system is.

Comment: You've apparently not dealt with Vista UAC/VirtualStore before, devinb.

Comment: I upvoted your comment (and your answer) because you're absolutely right. That virtual store doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check `\UserName\Documents\AppData\Local\VirtualStore` (or whatever `%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore` equates to) and see if somehow you're running into Vista's virtual store with your editor.

([This article](http://blog.bits-in-motion.com/2009/05/vista-registry-weirdness.html) explains some of how the virtual store works.)

Comment: Thanks! I found the latest version of my PHP file in the Virtual Store. I must be copying the old version while viewing the Virtual Store version in my editor. Vista really sucks!